# PHP crc32() only numbers

Tags: php, crc32

I have a MD5 hash: **10f86782177490f2ac970b8dc4c51014**

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=10f86782177490f2ac970b8dc4c51014
Result: **c74e16d9**

but PHP: crc32('10f86782177490f2ac970b8dc4c51014');
Result: **-951183655**

I don't understand!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's only a matter of **representation of the data** :

- `c74e16d9` is the **[hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)** representation
- and `-951183655` is the **[decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)** representation.

And here's a portion of code to illustrate that :

```
$crc = crc32('10f86782177490f2ac970b8dc4c51014');
var_dump($crc);
var_dump(dechex($crc));
```

It'll display :

```
int -951183655
string 'c74e16d9' (length=8)
```

Which corresponds to :

- The decimal representation of the value of your CRC
- and, after that, the hexadecimal represenation of that same value.